# How to create a Maven distributable

Tags: java, maven, deployment, release, distribution

I would like to create a ZIP distributable for my java application with Maven with the following structure :

**/lib -> my generated jars (several modules core.jar, app.jar ... )**

**/config -> several configuration files (app.properties, ...)**

**/3rdparty -> all jar dependencies (commons-lang.jar, log4j.jar ... )**

**/scripts -> helper scripts (start.sh ... )**

I would like to deploy this in any client machine and run as :

java -cp ../lib:../3rdparty -Dprop.file=app.properties [main.class]

I have read quite a lot about the maven assembly plugin but have not found a satisfactory answer on how to ahcieve this.

Comment: Does the client-side app. have a GUI?

Comment: No GUI. This is a single standalone java app fully controlled by JConsole (JMX exposed beans).

Comment: Got it.  That rules out my favorite installer, [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Have you considered creating a packaged installer? See: http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Maven Assembly plugin is the right thing to use here. There's plenty of examples on how to use it out there, here are some:

- [Maven creating flat zip assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500758/maven-creating-flat-zip-assembly)
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/howto.html
- [maven-assembly plugin - how to create nested assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522778/maven-assembly-plugin-how-to-create-nested-assemblies)

Answer (score 1):

The are of the scripts folder with starting scripts can be done via the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) which creates scripts for running/starting applications. 
To create a single archive which contains all that stuff you can use the maven-assembly-plugin.